# copying data from one table to another table for different database servers in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have to insert table data from the test server database to prod server database in Oracle. Both table definitions are same.

Comment: you could setup a database link between the 2, or export the tables from test and import into live

Comment: Thank you. I will use Import and export.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [**DATA PUMP**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_overview.htm) feature. It is a server based bulk data movement infrastructure.

1. **EXPDP** from source database and create a dump file on the source server.
2. **Move** the file to the destination server.
3. **IMPDP** on the destination database.

Look at few examples [here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Datapump).